# How can we perform conditional cross join on 1=1 in sql query?

Tags: sql, join, cartesian-product, cross-join

Initially, I have a query like below, doing a join on 1=1. (It's simply doing a cross join, which selects all rows from the first table and all rows from the second table and shows as a cartesian product, i.e. with all possibilities.)

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON 1=1
```

**Problem:** Optimize this query in such a way, it will show only the records for a particular ID and if we don't have an ID or have a NULL in the ID then it will show the result same as previously(1=1). So I wrote the script below.

```
Declare @T2id as int;
Set @T2id = 123;

SELECT * FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON 
            -- left side of join on statement
                CASE
                   WHEN @T2id Is NULL
                       THEN 1
                   ELSE
                        t2.Id
                END 
            = 
            -- right side of join on statement
                CASE
                   WHEN @T2id Is NULL
                       THEN 1
                   ELSE
                        @T2id
                END
```

Can anyone confirm, is it good or we can have a better approach than this?

Comment: For better performance I would run two separate queries: one for the cartesian product, and another for a subset of it. A single, combined query can suffer from performance.

Comment: _can_ suffer performance, depending on the dbms used. I.e. add a dbms tag to the question!

Comment: It's generally better to use regular `AND`/`OR` instead of `case` _expressions_ in the `ON` clause.

Comment: So if `@T2id = 399`, and `t2.Id = 399` doesn't exist, do you still want the `cross join` or an empty set?

Answer (score 0):

I think your way of presenting a cross-join is something I haven't seen before.

My view is it's simpler to read and understand if you just:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
```

As for the question, assuming SQL Server (you didn't tag the RDBMS, but I guess from your variable declaration) you might consider:

```
IF ISNULL(@T2id,1) = 1
    SELECT * 
    FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2;
ELSE
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
    WHERE t2.id = @T2id;
```

Comment: Note that SQL has the `CROSS JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Why `ISNULL()`? Isn't OP supposed to query for `t2.id = 1`?

Comment: I don't think so. OP says `if we don't have an ID or have a NULL in the ID`. I suppose it could just as easily (and probably should) have been `IF @T2id IS NULL`